# Does bagged ice need a hechsher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I am looking for an answer which is a bit more expansive than "Ask your LOR".  I have not been able to find "bagged ice" on the lists of any kashrut agencies that post on their lists on the internet.

Comment: What are the ingredients? Does it list all of them or just says pure H2O?

Comment: Ingredients: ice

Answer (score 1):

No, at least for Passover, but I assume the same is true year-round as well:

https://askcrc.org/item/Passover/1828

Comment: Yeh, but I wasn't sure about that.  IF it's kosher, then it's kosher for Pesach.  But is it kosher to begin with?